# How to get the X and Y position of a UI button iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

Could somebody show me how to get the x and y position of a UIButton in cocoa?

The button moves on the screen when clicked and I want to use it's current position to position another UIBUtton relative to it.

I've tried using

```
CGRect rect=[myButton imageRectForContentRect];
```

The compiler tells me that myButton may not respond to imageRectForContentRect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use

```
myButton.frame
```

Specifically for position, use myButton.frame.origin.x and myButton.frame.origin.y. That would be the top left corner.
This is the easiest solution for finding a button's position.

Answer (score 5):

```
    CGPoint position = myButton.frame.origin;
```

This works for any UIView.

The compiler is right (as it's prone to be): there is no method called `imageRectForContentRect`. There is, however, `imageRectForContentRect:` which takes a CGRect as its argument. You don't have to use it to get the position.