# xcode: get y-position of uibutton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I know that's quite an easy one but I haven't found anything about it.
All I want is how I can get the y-position of a unbutton?

I hope that anyone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the x and y position of a UI button IPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319642/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-position-of-a-ui-button-iphone)

Answer (score 5):

Since `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView` you can simply use

```
 button.frame.origin.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a more flexible way

```
CGRectGetMinY(button.frame)
```

for example you can get the mid Y pos like this

```
CGRectGetMidY(button.frame)
```